# Why does Puma shutdown shortly after deploying?

Tags: server, puma, ruby-on-rails-7, render.com

## Problem statement

I'm deploying my Rails 7 app on render.com and shortly after launching, the logs show that Puma is shutting down the workers. The config file is mostly unmodified from what ships with Rails.

## Question

Is this expected behavior, to shut down the workers shortly after deploying? Is there somewhere I can go inspect what's happening under the hood?

### Log output

```
Sep 10 05:21:59 PM  ==> Starting service with 'bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb'
Sep 10 05:22:01 PM  [70] Puma starting in cluster mode...
Sep 10 05:22:01 PM  [70] * Puma version: 5.6.4 (ruby 3.1.1-p18) ("Birdie's Version")
Sep 10 05:22:01 PM  [70] *  Min threads: 5
Sep 10 05:22:01 PM  [70] *  Max threads: 5
Sep 10 05:22:01 PM  [70] *  Environment: production
Sep 10 05:22:01 PM  [70] *   Master PID: 70
Sep 10 05:22:01 PM  [70] *      Workers: 4
Sep 10 05:22:01 PM  [70] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✖) phased
Sep 10 05:22:01 PM  [70] * Preloading application
Sep 10 05:22:07 PM  [70] * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:10000
Sep 10 05:22:07 PM  [70] Use Ctrl-C to stop
Sep 10 05:22:07 PM  [70] - Worker 1 (PID: 77) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
Sep 10 05:22:07 PM  [70] - Worker 2 (PID: 83) booted in 0.01s, phase: 0
Sep 10 05:22:07 PM  [70] - Worker 0 (PID: 75) booted in 0.03s, phase: 0
Sep 10 05:22:07 PM  [70] - Worker 3 (PID: 93) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0
Sep 10 05:23:15 PM  [69] === puma shutdown: 2022-09-10 22:23:15 +0000 ===
Sep 10 05:23:15 PM  [69] - Goodbye!
Sep 10 05:23:15 PM  [69] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
```

### Puma config file

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

worker_timeout 3600 if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV", "development") == "development"

port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }

if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") == "production"
  workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 4 }
end

if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") == "production"
  preload_app!
end

# --- START modified config from what ships with Rails 7 ---
on_worker_boot do
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end

lowlevel_error_handler do |e|
  Bugsnag.notify(e)
end
# --- END modified config from what ships with Rails 7 ---

plugin :tmp_restart
```